# Using Sed to add counter to keyword

Tags: text-processing, sed

Suppose I have a file like this.

```
Keyword "name"
aaa bbb
ccc ddd

Keyword "another name"
eee fff
ggg
hhh iii
```

and so on.

I want to change the keyword lines in the file to have counters starting from a given number. For example if I want to number the keyword lines starting from 5 the keyword lines would look like

```
Keyword "5 - name"
Keyword "6 - another name"
```

and so on. All the other lines in the file are not changed.

Is there a way to do this thanks.

Comment: Does your file actually contain unicode quotes (`“ ”`) as you show or are they normal quotes (`" "`)? Also, does this _need_ to be done using sed or are you open to other tools?

Comment: Just normal quotes. Prefer sed if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, you could use the non-standard `R` command to read and insert indices from a pre-generated sequence, with a second invocation of sed to rearrange the result:

```
printf '%d\n' {5..100} | sed '/^Keyword/R /dev/stdin' file | 
    sed '/^Keyword/{N; s/Keyword "\([^"]*\)"\n\(.*\)/Keyword "\2 - \1"/}'
```

However I would suggest using `perl` or `awk` for this task instead - for example

```
awk -v k=5 '/^Keyword/ {sub(/^Keyword \"/, sprintf("Keyword \"%d - ", k++))} 1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not tied to `sed`, it's very easy to do in `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN{$k=4};s/Keyword "/$& . ++$k . " - "/e' file 
Keyword "5 - name"
aaa bbb
ccc ddd

Keyword "6 - another name"
eee fff
ggg
hhh iii
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.